# How to capture clicks on header in wxPython grids

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to sort columns in wxPython grids and for that I want to run a function when there is a left click in a column header. Now what is the right hierarchy to process the event and how would you run the function once it happens?

The class HeaderCtrl has the method EVT_HEADER_CLICK, but how can I include this method in my binds?

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_HEADER_CLICK,self.sortData)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the `wx.Grid.EVT_GRID_LABEL_LEFT_CLICK` event.

See: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/04/wxpython-grid-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_HEADER_CLICK,self.sortData)
```